# Is there a way to get Used disk space & Available space from Windows share in Prometheus

Tags: windows, prometheus, diskspace, mounted-volumes, shared-drive

Is there a way to get Used disk space & Available space from Windows share in Prometheus?

Only on an explicitly mounted drive on a Linux machine, does it seem to work with `node exporter`.

```
100 - ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="<instance>:9100",job="prometheus",mountpoint='/mount/pointName'} * 100) / node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="<instance>:9100",job="prometheus",mountpoint='mount/pointName'})
```

Kindly let me know if a similar option is present with `wmi exporter`.